# Which event is fired after serializeRowData in jqGrid?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, mvcjqgrid

I have two jqGrids on a page. The idea is to display a confirmation dialog when a drop down value is updated and when the user presses enter to save the record both jqGrids get reloaded.

Here's my column model:

```
{
    key: false, name: 'InterestedValue', index: 'InterestedValue', editable: true,
    sortable: false, formatter: 'select', width: '120px', search: false,
    edittype: 'select',
    editoptions: {
        value: InterestedStatusList,
        //afterSaveCell: function (rowid, cellname, value, iRow, iCol) {
        //    alert("after savecell" + rowid + " cellname= " + cellname);
        //    //$(this).trigger('reloadGrid');
        //},
        successfunc: function (response) {
            alert("success");
            //FLAG = true;
            $(this).trigger('reloadGrid')
            return true;
        }

    }
},
```

And event,

```
serializeRowData: function (postdata) {
   var response = JSON.stringify(postdata);
   var s = '';
   $(postdata).each(function (index, data) {
       //s += '<option value="' + index + '">' + data + '</option>';
       $.each(data, function (k, v) {
           if(k=="InterestedValue")
            s += v;//'<option value="' + k + '">' + v + '</option>';
       });

   });
   //
   if (s == "2_1") {
       if (confirm('Are you sure you want to deactivate this record? ')) {
           // do things if OK
           return postdata;
       }
       else
           return false;
   }
   return postdata;
},
```

I am able to get the edit action method called with data after the `serializeRowData` event. But I can't figure out how to trigger the reload of the Grids **after the update is done** successfully. So please tell me which event gets fired after the `serializeRowData`. I tried the `successfunc` in the column as well, but this is fired as soon as the I click the row and it goes into Edit-mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the details @Oleg.

The **serializeRowData** method I posted earlier was able to put up the JavaScript confirmation dialog for the user before deactivation of the record. Here's how I managed to reload the jqGrids after the update was done on the server.

I used the editRow

```
$(gridId).jqGrid("editRow", 'kkk', true, '', '', '', '', reload)
```

And in the reload method, I triggered the reloading of jqGrids as

```
function reload(rowid, result) {
var s = '';
var o = false;
var postdata = JSON.stringify(result);
$(jQuery.parseJSON(postdata)).each(function (index, data) {
    $.each(data, function (k, v) {
        s += k + ":" + v + " --- ";
        if (k == "responseText")
        {
            if (v.indexOf("Deactivated") != -1)
                o = true;
        }
        s += k + ":" + v + " --- ";
    });

});

if (o ==true) {
    //reload both grids
    $("#grid1").trigger("reloadGrid");
    $("#grid2").trigger("reloadGrid");
}  }
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider to display the confirmation dialog if the user choose the "dangerous" value and *before* the value will be sent to the server. To implement this you can use

```
{
    name: 'InterestedValue', ...
    edittype: 'select',
    editoptions: {
        value: InterestedStatusList,
        dataEvents: [
            {
                type: 'change',
                fn: function () {
                    var newValue = $(this).val();
                    if (newValue === "2_1" && !confirm('Are you sure you want to deactivate this record?')) {
                        $(this).val("2_0"); // set some another value
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can use `beforeEditRow` callback of inline editing, but the exact place *where* you should specify it depends on **how you use** inline editing (direct call of `editRow`, usage of `inlineNav`, usage of `formatter: "actions"` or some other) and from the version of jqGrid (till the version 4.7), [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) (see [readme](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/README.md) and [wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki)) or [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=102663) which you use.